# unable to decode JSON

Tags: php, actionscript-3, json

I 'm passing a JSON encoded URL to php generated through my flash program

Here is the what i get when  I do a trace

```
myObject=%5B%7B%22fullname%22%3A%22jon%20jay%20junior%22%2C%22role%22%3A%22ADMIN%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22jjj%22%7D%5D
```

at the php end

```
$jsonString = urldecode($_POST['myObject']);
$jsonString = str_replace("\\", "", $jsonString);
$data = JSON_decode($jsonString);
print_r($data);
```

but I get nothing what am I doing wrong here?

code in flash

```
var people:Array = new Array();
var person:Object = new Object();
var url:String = "http://localhost/ping.php";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
person.fullname = "jon jay junior";
person.username = "jjj";
person.role = "ADMIN";
people.push(person);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
requestVars.myObject = JSON.encode(people);
request.data = requestVars;
loader.load(request);
trace(request.data);
```

Help!! Any one?

Comment: do you encode it properly when you send the data through flash?
what happens if you remove the decode line?

Comment: may i see the code where the JSON string is generated and where it's encoded/sent?

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the problem, but I think you shouldn't try to url-decode the $_POST data, as it's been decoded already by the php engine.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible that you don't have the JSON extension installed/enabled and your php.ini file is suppressing errors.  If you're using json_decode() other places then ignore everything I'm about to say.

If you're not sure and want to check to see if the JSON extension is installed just pop this code snippet into a new PHP file and view it in your browser:

```
The JSON extension is <?php print ( ! in_array( 'json', get_loaded_extensions( ) ) ) ? 'NOT' : '' ?> installed and enabled.
```

If you get the message "The JSON extension is NOT installed and enabled.", then that's what your problem is.  If the word "NOT" is...well...NOT in the output, then this isn't your problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using JSON_decode other places and it works fine ...I'm just stuck with the encode part here and i don't know why :( ??

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "%5B%7B%22fullname%22%3A%22jon%20jay%20junior%22%2C%22role%22%3A%22ADMIN%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22jjj%22%7D%5D";

$jsonString = urldecode($str);
$jsonString = str_replace("\\", "", $jsonString);
$data = JSON_decode($jsonString);
print_r($data);
```

That works fine.  Are you sure the value passed through is a POST?  Or maybe it isn't being decoded?  Echo out the value of $jsonString at each step.  If you use firebug, you can examine the Net panel to see the values that get sent to the php instead of using trace.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since my first thought was a bust, try this:

```
$jsonString = urldecode($_POST['myObject']);
print '1: ' . $jsonString . '<br />';
$jsonString = str_replace("\\", "", $jsonString);
print '2: ' . $jsonString . '<br />';
$data = JSON_decode($jsonString);
print_r($data);
```

See if you get any output from either #1 or #2.  If you don't get anything from #1, change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and try that.  If you don't get anything from THAT...then I'd have to say it's a Flash issue.  If that's the case, I'm sorry, but I can't help you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i'm decoding my json encoded data this way..

`$data   = urldecode(utf8_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data'])));
$decoded_result = json_decode($data);`

btw: did you add the appropriate event handler to your URLLoader instance ?

[update]
here is an example that works for me..

```
//loader event handler
function ioHandler (evt:IOErrorEvent): void { trace("IOError: "+ evt.text ); }
function httpHandler (evt:HTTPStatusEvent): void { trace("HTTPStatus: "+ evt.status ); }
function completeHandler (evt:Event): void { trace(complete" ); }

var person:Object = new Object();
    person.fullname = "jon jay junior";
    person.username = "jjj";
    person.role = "ADMIN";

var people:Array = new Array();
    people.push(person);

var vars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    vars.data = JSON.encode(people);

var request:URLRequest  = new URLRequest();
    request.url         = "http://localhost/data.php"; 
    request.data        = vars;

var loader:URLLoader    = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat   = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioHandler);
    loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpHandler);
    loader.load(request);
```

and for the serverside, this script

```
//the server side

<?php

$data = urldecode(utf8_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['data']))); 

$decoded_result = json_decode($data);

print_r($decoded_result);

?>
```

which produces the following the "response" view in firebug

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [username] => jjj
            [fullname] => jon jay junior
            [role] => ADMIN
        )

)
```

hope this helps..
kindest

Comment: Yes I'm using the event handler and the trace shows the output on the flash side but i get nothing while decoding in php

Comment: I get this error in flash after when use your code and try to return the value back to flash

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@2da693d1 to flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent