# JSON encoding in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, json

I have this code which Im using to pass data in JSON encoded format to php. Is there a way i can check at the php end if it was received and beamed in proper format?

```
var people:Array = new Array();
    var person:Object = new Object();
    var url:String = "http://localhost/ping.php";
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    person.fullname = "jon jay junior";
    person.username = "jjj";
    person.role = "ADMIN";
    people.push(person);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    requestVars.myObject = JSON.encode(people);
    request.data = requestVars;
    loader.load(request);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to decode JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327323/unable-to-decode-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you should look at the request with Firebug, LiveHTTPHeaders, or a similar tool (there are several for Firefox).  This will let you see the format of the data.

If `$_REQUEST['myObject']` is indeed `null` in PHP, then something is wrong.  You should really attach a `loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError);` to check for problems and/or run with the debug Flash player so you can see any exceptions going on.

If you are running this in a browser, a debug trick is to call Firebug's `console.log` via an `ExternalInterface.call()`

Answer (score 1):

You could log the response to a file (`print_r($_POST)`), to a database or something like that, but the easiest way if you are debugging the code is using firebug, httpfox (both for firefox) or some other tool that lets you see the http requests and responses. Then you could see exactly what are you sending to the php script.

Answer (score 0):

check if `$_POST['data']` or `$_REQUEST['data']` is set and not empty.